# use pyinstaller to build exe from webpy

Tags: python, pyinstaller, web.py

I was trying to use '**pyinstaller**' to turn my '**webpycode.py**' into a .exe like '**webpycode.exe**',
and I do have successfully created a webpycode.exe. 
When I executed it, I got this [telling me the inter face is 8080 ("http://0.0.0.0:8080/")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whYNu.jpg)

BUT when I visited this 8080, I got an ImportError: **No module named webpycode**
[here is the detailed pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VVB1.jpg)

P.S.  When I directly use the 'webpycode.py', I can visit 8080 without any problems. Everything is working alright. So  I assume there is something I don't know between **webpy** and **pyinstaller**

Actually, I'm not a native english speaker, but I have been searching for an answer for a whole day and got nothing useful.Therefore, I come to stackoverflow hoping anyone can help me. please help.

Any thing could be useful.

Comment: Just to get some basic info: what version of pyinstaller, and what version of Python?

Comment: @Jaxian pyinstaller is 3.2 and Python is 2.7.9 anything wrong? and thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is the pyinstaller command / spec file you are using to build the executable? Can you paste in your webpycode.py file code as an example? When I use pyinstaller, I've had to specify a lot of hidden imports in the spec file to get my apps to run correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
pyinstaller.exe webcode.py --hidden-import=webcode
```